Unable to detect USB flash drive after ejecting in middle of operation; is there any way to make it working again?
I have USB 3.0 flash drive (64 GB) and it was very much detectable in Mac (macOS 14.4.1) but recently while making it bootable USB flash drive using winDiskWriter app, I have ejected in middle of process after getting error of unable to copy.
Now I am not able to detect the USB flash drive at all, tried various approach.
diskutil list does not show, dis utility app does not show,
In Windows, it is getting detected but unable to format at all, saying 0 bytes.
It seems like it corrupted but I believe there must be some way/ tool or command line approach to make it detectable and working again.
For note, system detect other USB devices properly.

You Probably need to re-write the partition map. Do you have access to a linux machine?  If you do you can try fdisk -l or parted -l to see the status of the drive.  Then you could write a new partition map with parted -a optimal /dev/sdX mklable gpt where X is your drive

After plugging in your flash, issue the command system_profiler SPUSBDataType. Do you see the 64GB flash listed?  Does it get an identifier (diskN)?

no I cant see USB under system_profiler SPUSBDataType

If you can’t see it there, then it simply isn’t being recognized by the system.  This means you can’t send commands to it.  It may have coincidentally died at the time of accidental disconnection
